# Does jQuery actually use camelcaps to reference multiword css fields?

Tags: jquery, css

In jQuery, are multiword css fields condensed to camelCaps? For instance.

```
$("#item").css("marginBottom");
```

not

```
$("#item").css("margin-bottom");
```

On my machine running Firefox 3.6.6 with jQuery JavaScript Library v1.4.2, the answer seems to be no. doing `$("#item").css("marginBottom");` gives me a warning about invalid css field and that the declaration was dropped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I'm wrong - it seems internally it camelCases it. Here's a snippet of code that grabs the margin bottom ( tested in Fx 3.6 ):

```
el = document.body;
$('el').css('margin-bottom', '20px')
computed = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle( el, null )

computed['marginBottom'] // 0px
```

**Update:** Here's the camelcasing then lowercasing code from jQuery:

```
x = 'marginBottom'.replace( /([A-Z])/g, '-$1').toLowerCase()
```

Comment: So the camelCasing is only for plain javascript then right?

such as x.style.marginBottom="15px"

Comment: That makes sense then, the properties themselves had to be camelCased to comply with javascript's variable naming conventions, but since jQuery represents them as strings, having the little dash is ok.